# unity c# transform.right problem. Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a script which when pressed F will create an object and than it will go right which works fine but when i added another script which will change the bool when pressed A(D means right, A means left) objects just stopped moving. Can anyone help.

I tried canging transform.right to -transform.right or speed to - speed but it didn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PrefabDuplicating : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform shootingPoint;
    public GameObject prefabForBullet;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            Instantiate(prefabForBullet, shootingPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetRotationOfBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool right;
    void Start()
    {
        right = true;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && right == false)
        {
           right = true;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && right == true)
        {
            right = false;

        }

    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Transform shootingPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;

            if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == false)
            {
                rb.velocity = -transform.right * speed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: time to debug :P however, your shoot you would have to have right being true AND false to fire left.. so.. perhaps start there

Comment: In your third script you've placed the close curly bracket in the wrong spot. Additionally you could safe yourself the second if condition and use an else. If it's not right then it's left.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == false)` being inside of `if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == true){}`.

The code will reach `if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == false)` only when `GetRotationOfBullet.right` is `true`. This makes `rb.velocity = -transform.right * speed;` unreachable.

Try changing your code to something like this

```
if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == true)
{
    rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
}
else if (GetRotationOfBullet.right == false)
{
    rb.velocity = -transform.right * speed;
}
```